# String view literals in header file

Tags: c++, c++17, string-literals, string-view

I've got a class that has a bunch of constant strings, in the form of:

```
using namespace std::string_view_literals;
class T {
  static const constexpr std::string_view something1 = "Alice"sv;
  static const constexpr std::string_view something2 = "Bob"sv;
  static const constexpr std::string_view something3 = "Charlie"sv;

  ...
};
```

I'm currently `using` the `string_view_literals` namespace, but this isn't good practice in a header file, and generates warnings:

`Using namespace directive in global context in header [-Wheader-hygiene]` (clang)

`literal operator suffixes not preceded by '_' are reserved for future standardization [-Wliteral-suffix]` (gcc7)

I'd like to look at other options.

1. Ignore the warnings
2. Directly import the one literal I'm using, instead of the whole namespace

   `using std::string_view_literals::operator""sv`
3. Since this is a constexpr constant, perhaps I should just call the constructor directly, knowing it has no runtime memory or CPU overhead:

   `static const constexpr something1 = std::string_view("Alice");`
4. Something else?

Comment: Did you mean `static auto constexpr something1`?

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin I accidentally left out the type, `std::string_view`. Fixed

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is pretty short and doesn't pollute anything:

```
class T {
    using sv = std::string_view;
    static constexpr auto something1 = sv("Alice");
    static constexpr auto something2 = sv("Bob");
    static constexpr auto something3 = sv("Charlie");
};
```

If you really want to use the literal, you could wrap your class in another not-intended-to-be-named `namespace` and then bring it back into the outer namespace:

```
namespace _private {
    using namespace std::string_view_literals;

    class T {
        static constexpr auto something1 = "Alice"sv;
        static constexpr auto something2 = "Bob"sv;
        static constexpr auto something3 = "Charlie"sv;
    };
}

using _private::T;
```

---

Note that writing `static constexpr const` is redundant. `constexpr` variables are implicitly `const`.

Comment: The first imposed solution is wrong. `sv("Alice")` still invokes the "const char*" constructor effectively forcing a strlen-call on the parameter --> defeating the purpose of the literal. `std::string_view ("alice\0foo").length (); //--> 5` `"alice\0foo"sv.length (); // --> 9`

Comment: @Xatian Is OP using string literals with embedded nulls? Otherwise, it doesn't defeat the purpose of the literal...

Comment: what is the purpose of a literal if it is not to avoid constructing the object? (in this case const char* to string_view). please explain...

Comment: @Xatian There's no cost to constructing any objects here - it happens at compile time. And even if the `string_view`s themselves weren't `constexpr`, the compiler would certainly optimize the strlen calls - since it knows what's going on.

Comment: You are right. I found no way to init a (none `constexpr`) string_view where a none-ancient compiler doesn't remove the strlen-call. But still --> It should be stated in the answer that you expect the compiler to help you out since that would add to the understanding of what is going on. Therefore I think my comment is still fine :-) Thank you!